# Getting started with Instant Messaging on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, silverlight, xmpp, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-8

here is my scenario.
I have this windows phone 8 app, that has a routing history that shows all the comments left by people who is currently using this document, now when i click on one of these people's comments or picture(that is next to the comment), my app should be able too see what social network that person is on and then it should be able to start a instant messaging if the need was there... we will use facebook as a start, i know i need a XMPP protocol to access this feature, now i want to know if someone can please send me to a link(tutorial) with code to help me understand how to implement this with the help of the facebook api?

if there is such a question already on stack overflow please show me :)

i use c#/Silverlight

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe Facebook is using XMPP as its backbone for communication.
Unless you want users to connect to the same social network, you would need to enable your own means of communication.

I have some trouble understanding what you are actually asking.
But if you want to use FB, then just read up on XMPP (Jabber) and start from there.
It is fairly simple, and there are opensource clients out there where you can dismantle code and learn by understanding what others have done.